# Calling a class's static method in Groovy Console

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I have a Groovy class that has no constructor, and contains only `static` methods. In GroovyConsole, after importing the class and then trying to call a static method of the class, I get a

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.boblablob.lawblog.bla.Person
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at ConsoleScript23.run(ConsoleScript23:4)
```

How can I call a class's static method in Groovy Console?

Comment: Do you have sample code? Sometimes the devil is in the details.

Comment: @BalRog, I'm running the below in Grails Console:

        `import com.boblablob.lawblog.bla.Person`
        `Person.someStaticMethod()`

Comment: Groovy console, or Grails console?

Comment: @tim_yates Grails Console

Comment: Missing the library in your classpath?